# how to download custom software and install using WIX

Tags: wix

I am writing managed bootstrapper application and would like to make it work like Web-based installer (force it to download msi from webserver). 
Where will product be downloaded by default? Why SourceFile is mandatory for download of package?

please share sample code.

Answer (score 0):

[Separating the concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns):

1. Managed bootstrapper application

   Great. The standard application is very basic. The managed bootstrapper application for WiX itself shows how creative you can get.
2. Work like Web-based installer

   From the following questions, it seems you know about the [DownloadUrl](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/msipackage.html) attribute.
3. Where will product be downloaded by default?

   It would be a special case to have to know this. The bootstrapper engine (burn) is a package manager and takes care of performing operations with the downloaded package.
4. Why SourceFile is mandatory for download of package?

   SourceFile indicates the location on your build machine. WiX creates a checksum from it so burn can tell if the download is corrupted or different than what was planned.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explaination, can you please share sample code using downloadurl attribute. I require to mention path where software is downloaded to user - is there any attribute for same?